# LINQ: How to find most popular item from column

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc

I want to find which item is most popular in my **Orders** table with the **'ItemTitle'** column.

ItemTitle has the following:

- King burger
- Hawaiian
- Classico Italiano
- Tiramisu
- King burger
- King burger
- Classico Italiano
- Classico Italiano
- King burger

What is the best LINQ query to find which item is most popular? Thank you!

Here is my try:

```
 return _DbContext.Orders.GroupBy(x => x.ItemTitle).Where(g => g.Count() > 1).OrderByDescending(g => g.Count()).Select(g => g.Key).Take(1);
```

It's working, however, it has a bug. The bug is Orders has **Quantity** column.
ex:
In the list below there are 4 King Burger's x 1 - Quantity.
If the Tiramisu has x 10 - Quantity, Now the most popular item should be the tiramisu.

Comment: Can you provide attempts you've made towards producing the solution yourself? Also it might help to think about how you would come to the solution (semantics aside) - e.g, _group the titles together to find the number of times it appears and return that_

Comment: My ways can be done with for loop. Unfortunately, I don't have too much experience with LINQ. Most often I use Where, Select, FirstOrDefault, Count, Max, Average and Include

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't care about ties, then you can use this:

```
var query =
    orders
        .GroupBy(x => x.ItemTitle, x => x.Quantity)
        .Select(x => new { ItemTitle = x.Key, Quantity = x.Sum() })
        .OrderByDescending(x => x.Quantity)
        .Take(1)
        .SingleOrDefault();
```

Otherwise, if tracking ties are important, then this works:

```
var querySupportingTies =
    orders
        .GroupBy(x => x.ItemTitle, x => x.Quantity)
        .Select(x => new { ItemTitle = x.Key, Quantity = x.Sum() })
        .ToLookup(x => x.Quantity, x => x.ItemTitle)
        .OrderByDescending(x => x.Key)
        .Select(x => new
        {
            Quantity = x.Key,
            ItemTitles = x.ToArray()
        })
        .Take(1)
        .SingleOrDefault();
```